# Android - NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

Tags: java, android, security, networking, httpurlconnection

I have an event on a **Button** which makes a **HttpURLConnection** in order to access an API Service which is on my local server to retrieve a JSON. When I click the **Button** it gives me :

**"D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default"**

But then when I press again the **Button** it gives me the JSON string. So my question is : how do I make it to give me the JSON the first time I press the **Button** without pressing it 2 times.

This is the code

```
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        json = reader.readLine();

        return json;
```

Comment: show me your code

Comment: That debugging message does not indicate any sort of problem. I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve], and focus less on that message and more on the specific results from your code. `HttpURLConnection` is synchronous, and so you know exactly what you are getting back from your first request -- what is it?

Comment: URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            connection.setDoInput(true);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            json = reader.readLine();

            return json;

Comment: I edited my post by adding the code. Maybe this is producing that message.